# How to add key to NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have a `NSMutableArray` looks like this. And I want to pass this Array to another ViewController and use the elements of it. But I'm confused about how to add keys to each element. For example, `{@"bus_route_key":@"733"}`

Is there a way to init the Array with keys? Or should i create `NSDictionary` for this?

```
@[
 @[
  @733,
  @"Oakleigh - Box Hill via Clayton & Monash University & Mt Waverley",
  @"Oakleigh Railway Station/Johnson St",
  @"2016-04-05T11:44:00Z"
  ],
 @[
  @631,
  @"Southland - Waverley Gardens via Clayton & Monash University",
  @"Southland Shopping Centre/Karen St",
  @"2016-04-05T11:46:00Z"
  ],
 @[
  @703,
  @"Middle Brighton - Blackburn via Bentleigh & Clayton & Monash University (SMARTBUS Service)",
  @"Luntar Rd/Centre Rd",
  @"2016-04-05T11:50:00Z"
  ]
 ];
```

Comment: Yes use a dictionary; arrays don't have keys, just indexes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
NSArray *mainArray = @[
 @[
  @733,
  @"Oakleigh - Box Hill via Clayton & Monash University & Mt Waverley",
  @"Oakleigh Railway Station/Johnson St",
  @"2016-04-05T11:44:00Z"
  ],
 @[
  @631,
  @"Southland - Waverley Gardens via Clayton & Monash University",
  @"Southland Shopping Centre/Karen St",
  @"2016-04-05T11:46:00Z"
  ],
 @[
  @703,
  @"Middle Brighton - Blackburn via Bentleigh & Clayton & Monash University (SMARTBUS Service)",
  @"Luntar Rd/Centre Rd",
  @"2016-04-05T11:50:00Z"
  ]
 ];

NSMutableArray *newArray = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSArray *arr in mainArray) {

        NSDictionary *dict = @{
                               @"key1" : [arr objectAtIndex:0],
                               @"key2" : [arr objectAtIndex:1],
                               @"key3" : [arr objectAtIndex:2]
                               };

    [newArray addObject:dict];
}

DLOG(@"New Arr : %@", newArray);

//you can access by key like this

for (NSDictionary *dict in newArray) {

    DLOG(@"%@", [dict valueForKey:@"key1"]);
    DLOG(@"%@", [dict valueForKey:@"key2"]);
    DLOG(@"%@", [dict valueForKey:@"key3"]);
}
```

Hope it'll help you..:)

Comment: Works like magic, that's exactly what i want. Thanks a lot for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

Wow, hey there Melbournian.

You should have a NSMutableArray that contains NSMutableDictionaries and setup each bus line to be more structured:

```
(
  {
    "route": 733,
    "line_name": "Oakleigh - Box Hill via Clayton & Monash University & Mt Waverley",
    "stop": "Oakleigh Railway Station/Johnson St",
    "time": "2016-04-05T11:44:00Z"
  },

  //Insert other line dictionaries
)
```

Comment: hah, melbourne coder it is. Thanks man, i've already added Dictionaries in Array!

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, your `NSMutableArray` contains `NSArrays`. These `NSArray`s need to be `NSDictionary`s or `NSMutableDictionary`s in your case.

Then you can edit the `bus_route_key` for example of the first element like this:
`[[yourList objectAtIndex:0] setInteger:1337 forKey:@"bus_route_key"]`
If you want to set a string, you need to use `setObject`

Answer (score 0):

you can convert your `NSArray` to `NSDictionary` as arrays doesn't contain keys and values arrays only have indexes

Comment: this should be a comment not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

My code will help you :)

```
  NSMutableArray *arrTitles = (NSMutableArray *)@[@{
     "route": 733,
     "line_name": "Oakleigh - Box Hill via Clayton & Monash University & Mt Waverley",
     "stop": "Oakleigh Railway Station/Johnson St",
     "time": "2016-04-05T11:44:00Z"
      },@{
    "route": 733,
    "line_name": "Oakleigh - Box Hill via Clayton & Monash University & Mt Waverley",
    "stop": "Oakleigh Railway Station/Johnson St",
    "time": "2016-04-05T11:44:00Z"
  }];
```

Answer (score -1):

Use below line of code:
    NSMutableDictionary *dict2 =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:attributeValues forKeys:attributeKeys];

Here attributeValues is the `NSArray` of values `NSDictionary`and attributeKeys is the `NSArray` of keys.

Refer below reference link :

http://hayageek.com/nsdictionary-nsmutabledictionary/

```
NSString * key1 =@"name";
NSString * obj1 =@"Hayagreeva";
NSString * key2 =@"age";
NSNumber * obj2 =[NSNumber numberWithInt:3];

//1.Empty dictionary. @{} dictionary representation and it is not for  NSMuableDictionary
NSDictionary * dict1 =[NSDictionary dictionary];
NSDictionary * dict2 =[[NSDictionary alloc] init];
NSDictionary * dict3 = @{};

//2.Dictionary with Single Object and Key
NSDictionary * dict4 =[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:obj1 forKey:key1];
NSDictionary * dict5 =@{key1:obj1};

//3.Dictionary with Multiple Object and Keys
//Objects and keys are sequentially terminated with nil
NSDictionary * dict6 = [NSDictionary
                        dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:obj1,key1,obj2,key2,nil];

NSDictionary * dict7 =[[NSDictionary alloc]
                       initWithObjectsAndKeys:obj1,key1,obj2,key2,nil] ;

//3.Dictionary with Multiple Object and Keys
NSDictionary *dict8 =[NSDictionary
                      dictionaryWithObjects:@[obj1,obj2]
                      forKeys:@[key1,key2]];
NSDictionary *dict9 =[[NSDictionary alloc]
                      initWithObjects:@[obj1,obj2]
                      forKeys:@[key1,key2]];
NSDictionary * dict10 =@{key1:obj1,key2:obj2};

//@[obj1,obj2] is the array representation.  dict6,dict7,dict8 are same.
NSDictionary *dict11 =[[NSDictionary alloc]
                       initWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:obj1,obj2,nil]
                       forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:key1,key2,nil]];

//4.Dictionary with another Dictionary
//@[obj1,obj2] is the array representation.  dict6,dict7,dict8 are same.
NSDictionary *dict12=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:dict8];
NSDictionary *dict13=[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:dict8];
```